# Saving data in pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pickle

I am using python to code and I have read online to use the pickle method to save games but I don't know how it works. I am trying to save my top score into a txt document so next time access the program the top score is saved.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)?

Comment: yes but I don't know what sterilization is

Comment: it's `serialization`. Read about it [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Comment: so would I do `pickle.dump(top_score)`

Comment: I LOLd at "yes but I don't know what sterilization is"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, quick example. Say you have your top scores saved in a dict:

```
top_scores = {10000: "Joey", 8000: "Mary", 6000: "Tommy", 4000: "Susie", 2000: "Bobby"}
```

All you do to pickle it to disk is:

```
import pickle

with open("top_scores.pickle", "wb") as scores:
    pickle.dump(top_scores, scores)
```

If you later want to unpickle the data, simply do this:

```
import pickle

with open("top_scores.pickle", "rb") as scores:
    top_scores = pickle.load(scores)
```

Of course, there's much more you can do, but this should get you started.

Comment: sorry forgot to copy. **This error** `line 354, in <module>
    pickle.dump(top_score, score)
io.UnsupportedOperation: write`

Comment: I am confused were to put this code [my code:](http://www.mediafire.com/view/poglq29jg0tsivl/wah.py)

Comment: @Lioninn22 you need to switch the `"rb"` and `"wb"` parameters. You need to open the file in write-binary mode (`wb`) for writing using `pickle.dump()`, and in read-binary mode (`rb`) for reading using `pickle.load()`. Also, make sure your top scores are actually stored in a variable called `top_score`.

Comment: when I do that i get this error `with QUIT("top_score.pickle", "wb") as scores:
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Comment: @Lioninn22 why are you using `with QUIT(...)`?

Comment: because i want to save the data when i exit and i have `if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()` for exiting

Comment: and if i have it pickle the score when it opens then it will always be 0 because it starts as a zero. it is basically a high score.